# Print preview showing duplicate items on every print command

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Whenever I click on print and cancel print preview, again click on print and its showing double pages in print preview.

Is it normal behavior or something to fix within, can somebody please suggest?

```
//Javascript for print on click
$('.print').on("click", function(e){
    var divElements = $(".printable-content").html();
    var iframe = $('<iframe class="hidden" id="printer"></iframe>').appendTo('body');
    var printer = $('#printer');
    printer.contents().find('body').append("<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>Print Title</title></head><body>" + divElements + "</body>");
    setTimeout(function() {  
        printer.get(0).contentWindow.print();
        printer.remove();

    }, 250);
});

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Print Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="printable-content">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    This is printtable content
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    This is printtable content
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    This is printtable content
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="javascipt:;" class="print"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achive?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO The issue is everytime I print, and cancel the print preview, again hitting print is more than the pages showing as compared to the first print. Hope this clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't remove `printer` iframe inside setTimeout

Instead you can do this

```
$('.print').on("click", function(e) {

    if ($("#printer").length) {
        $("#printer").remove();
    }

    var divElements = $(".printable-content").html();
    var iframe = $('<iframe class="hidden" id="printer"></iframe>').appendTo('body');
    var printer = $('#printer');
    printer.contents().find('body').append("<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>Print Title</title></head><body>" + divElements + "</body>");
    setTimeout(function() {  
        printer.get(0).contentWindow.print();

    }, 250);
});
```

Comment: Is it? or you have to do anything extra? Because earlier you commented its not working..

Comment: Yes it is working, I was appending something additional in print, which also required to remove which I was not doing.